# React-calendar enable/create a touch swipe feature

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I'm currently using [React Calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar)
I would like to know if it is possible to enable a touch swipe event with it?
The objective is to swipe month to month left to right.
I have been the documentation without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm after this right now!